# How can I split my layout in 3 different swipe views

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, android-view, swipe

I have built an app which has an activity and the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dip" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:hint="Comment anything important about the next measurement(s)"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editText"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dip"
    tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want to split my layout in 3 different tabs, one will have the textView and the button, one the graphView and one the map. I think I have to do something with the ViewPager, but I don't understand the example on android guides (https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral), because it swipes across a collection of Fragment objects and not different layouts that I want.

How should I do it? Is there any other way to manage that?

---

**Updated question:**

I followed what BenjyTec proposed so I added the code in my activity and made the following 3 xml layouts:

fragment1.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:hint="Comment anything important about the next measurement(s)"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editText"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:text="Send" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="175dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dip"
    tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, the main layout (second.xml) is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But now when I run the app it crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.redbear.chat/com.redbear.chat.Chat}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.redbear.chat.Chat.onCreate(Chat.java:185)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

My activity is the following:

```
public class Chat extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);  //number of ViewPager pages that will be kept in storage while swiping
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
}

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentA();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentB();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentC();
        }
        return new FragmentA();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;  //number of Fragments inside the ViewPager
    }

}

public static class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

public static class FragmentC extends Fragment  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment3, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng patras = new LatLng(38.246639, 21.734573);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(patras, 14));
    updateLocationUI();
    UiSettings set = mMap.getUiSettings();
    set.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}

private void updateLocationUI() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    } catch (SecurityException e)  {
        Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create three Fragments with three different layouts and add them to the ViewPager following the example in the documentation.
Say you have three Fragments `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` and `FragmentC` with the according layouts `a_fragment.xml` with the TextView and the Button, `b_fragment.xml` with the GraphView and `c_fragment.xml` containing the map.

Now in your activity_main.xml layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Setup your ViewPager in MainActivity.java like this:

```
ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);  //number of ViewPager pages that will be kept in storage while swiping
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

Finally create a ViewPagerAdapter class like this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentA();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentB();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentC();
        }
        return new FragmentA();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;  //number of Fragments inside the ViewPager
    }

}
```

Now move the code for setting up the TextView, Button, GraphView, Map into the corresponding Fragments. The code inside the `onCreateView` of `FragmentB` for example would be like this:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false); 

    GraphView graphView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.graph);

    return rootView; 
}
```

In the same way, you move all the code for the Map into the according Fragment, which is in you case `FragmentC`.

Comment: It helped me, thank you very match, but now there is an error I guess with the map... Please see the update in my post.

Comment: The app might be crashing because you set up the Views (TextView, Button, GraphView, Map) inside `onCreate` of the `MainActivity`, but the layout of the `MainActivity` does not contain those Views anymore! So a `NullpointerException` is thrown. So you need to set up the Views in the corresponding Fragments. See my edited answer.

Comment: I have set the views now in the corresponding fragments, but it still throws a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error because of mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

Comment: Replace `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` inside `FragmentC` with `mapFragment.getMapAsync(getActivity);`. Hope this will finally make it work...

Comment: Ok fixed the last problem by using getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager() in the mapFragment initialization. Thank you a lot for giving me the answer!